# Das erste Mal, dass/ als?

Tags: grammar, style

I'm not sure if these sentences are correct:

> Das ist mein erstes Mal, dass ich eine Geschichte auf Deutsch schreibe.
>
> Das erste Mal, als ich anfing, Deutsch zu lernen, ist, war ich mit 19 Jahren.

What are the alternative for these sentences?

Comment: The first sentence is correct, the second doesn't work.

Comment: @PMF "dass" is correct here too?

Comment: Are you writing these German sentences yourself? Or are they from a reference book?

Comment: Yes. "als" would require some event in the past: "Das erste Mal, als ich eine Geschichte auf deutsch schrieb, war sie grauenhaft." Or with the correct form of the second sentence: "Als ich anfing, Deutsch zu lernen, war ich 19 Jahre alt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich hoffe, dass es in Ordnung ist, wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte. Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache, und du willst ja ohnehin Deutsch lernen.

**Erster Satz**

> Das ist *mein erstes Mal*, dass ich eine Geschichte auf Deutsch schreibe.

Der Satz ist grammatikalisch fehlerfrei. Aber die Phrase »mein erstes Mal« wird sehr selten verwendet, weil sich aus dem Kontext meist ohnehin klar ergibt, wessen erstes Mal das ist. Wenn nämlich im selben Satz »dass *ich* ... schreibe« steht, wird es wohl nicht Frau Maiers erstes Mal sein.

Also:

> Das ist **das erste Mal**, dass ich eine Geschichte auf Deutsch schreibe.

So, wie der Satz jetzt dasteht, ist er vollkommen in Ordnung. Ich würde den Satz aber trotzdem ganz anders formulieren:

> Ich schreibe jetzt zum ersten Mal eine Geschichte auf Deutsch.

Dadurch kann nämlich die unschöne Konstruktion mit »dass« vermieden werden.

**Zweiter Satz**

```
Das erste Mal, als ich anfing, Deutsch zu lernen, ist, war ich mit 19 Jahren.
```

Da steckten gleich mehrere Fehler drin! So wäre es richtig und obendrein schön:

> Als ich anfing Deutsch zu lernen, war ich 19 Jahre alt.

**»... war ich mit 19 Jahren«** ist leider ganz falsch. Richtig ist »war ich 19 Jahre alt« oder ganz einfach »war ich 19«. Die Formulierung `[Person] [Form von »sein«] [ganze Zahl zwischen 0 und ca. 120]` (also z.B. »Hans wurde 60« oder »Anna ist sieben geworden« impliziert immer, dass mit der Zahl das Alter der Person gemeint ist.

**»Das erste Mal ...«** Wie oft kann man anfangen eine Sprache zu lernen? Ich glaube das ist etwas, was man nur einmal macht. Falls du doch früher mal damit angefangen, es aber aufgegeben hast, und jetzt gerade einen zweiten Versuch unternimmst, dann könntest du schreiben:

> Als ich zum ersten Mal anfing Deutsch zu lernen, war ich 19 Jahre alt.

oder auch:

> Als ich das erste Mal anfing Deutsch zu lernen, war ich 19 Jahre alt.

Comment: anfing? Do you mean anfang?

Comment: Why is that you can use 'war' here?, [This post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41881/does-this-solution-to-using-vorgangspassiv-or-zustandspassiv-work-intellectuall?rq=1) suggests to me that some conjugation of 'wurde' should be used. How could I reconcile these two facts?

Comment: Ohhhh damn, I get it now. In the context here, we need the state only. Thank you so much! Your detailed answers form a large part of the German knowledge I have.

Comment: @Buraian: Ich war 19 Jahre alt = I was 19 years old. (I was in the state of being a 19 year old man) - Ich wurde 19 Jahre alt = I become 19 years old. (I turned into this state, so it was my 19th birthday.) But: Ich war 1965 geboren. (I was a born man in 1965) - Ich wurde 1965 geboren = I was born in 1965. (The act of birth happened in 1965)