# Does this solution to using Vorgangspassiv or Zustandspassiv work (intellectually)?

Tags: grammar-identification

Like many native English speakers, I have a problem deciding when to use the Vorgangspassive in German. For instance I tend to use sentences like

> Das Haus war im Jahr 1960 gebaut.

When what I mean to say is

> Das Haus wurde im Jahr 1960 gebaut.

I know that the difference is that the house was already built in 1960 in the first example but actually built in (during) 1960 in the second. But I still make the mistake often when not concentrating.

I have suddenly hit on the idea of translating wird/wurde to gets/got in my mind. So

> Das Haus wurde im Jahr 1960 gebaut.

Becomes

> The house got built in the year 1960.

And the difference becomes very clear to me.

I have never seen this method or translation before and so I thought I would ask if it is valid, or if it could lead to comprehension problems for me as my German improves, before I start to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the title to reflect your correction.

Comment: I cannot make grammatical sense of the title.

Comment: @CarstenS: I fixed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your translation, "The house *got built* in 1960," because it is a "point in time" construction, which uses the Vorgangspasiv. That is, the house "was built" *during* 1960 (and not before).

"Das Haus war im Jahr 1960 gebaut" is a "condition" passive, known in German as a 
Zustandpasiv. It is a "conditional" statement that means "the house "was" built (that is, standing) in 1960" (and, by implication, in 1959 and even earlier).

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that the best English counter-part to *Vorgangspassiv* is a continuous form, since it describes the current process (Vorgang):

> Das Haus wird gebaut. (The house is being built)

Similar:

> Die Radarkontrolle wird durchgeführt. (The speed control is being performed).

Opposed to this *Das Haus wurde 1960 gebaut.* describes the past, no process is taking place, you simply state the result (Zustand).

In both cases the house takes/took no active part.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is simply wrong! "Das Haus wurde 1960 gebaut" is most definitely Vorgangspassiv.

Comment: No, he's right. There aren't any continous forms in German, but *Vorgangspassiv* fills that gap for some often-used cases. For native speakers of English, with its structured tenses, this may be hard to understand but in German, tense, aspect and mood are intermingled heavily.

Comment: *Das Haus wurde 1960 gebaut.* is *Vorgangspassiv* indeed, because it uses *werden*. No further indicator required.

Answer (score 0):

> Das Haus war im Jahr 1960 gebaut.

This means: The house was a built house (it was not a grow house nor did it fall from the sky or materialize from thin air) in the year 1960. Maybe it was another kind of house (a grown house or a fallen house) in other years. - This meaning makes no sense.

---

> Das Haus wurde im Jahr 1960 gebaut.

This means: The act of building this house (turning it from the state of not being built into the state of being a built house) happened in the year 1960. Maybe other acts (planning, settlement, demolition) happened in other years. - This is what you want to say.